# using an if condition within html

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I am trying to use an if condition within a variable containing html.  I am getting errors with a standard condition and a ternary condition.  Am I going about this the right way, or is there a different way I should be doing this?

Both methods I have tried:

```
$test = "
 <tr>
   <th><a href=\"installs.php?column=username&order=" . $asc_or_desc . "\">Username<i class=\"fas fa-sort" . if($column == 'username'){ '-' . $up_or_down; } else {''} . "\"></i></a></th>
 </tr>
";
```

and tarnery:

```
$test = "
 <tr>
  <th><a href=\"installs.php?column=username&order=" . $asc_or_desc . "\">Username<i class=\"fas fa-sort" . $column == 'username' ? '-' . $up_or_down : '' . "\"></i></a></th>
 </tr>
";
```

Comment: What do both of the above approaches return right now and what output did you want instead?

Comment: `if` cannot be concatenated in PHP. The ternary operator's result can, but you probably should use brackets, as if to not have the concatenation precede the ternary operator.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use brackets around your operator, try this:

```
$test = "
 <tr>
  <th><a href=\"installs.php?column=username&order=" . $asc_or_desc . "\">Username<i class=\"fas fa-sort" . ($column == 'username' ? '-' . $up_or_down : '') . "\"></i></a></th>
 </tr>
";
```